# ASP.NET Simple User Login

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, authentication

I am using a simple login screen for users to login screen in asp.net forms c#.

I know how to valid so that the user has a unique username, etc.
I can do this easily.

My question is that once the user is logged in, how to I valide the user
between the different page. Keep in mind that I am not using the built in asp.net Membership and Roles table (There are some reasons why I do not want to use it).

My thought was that once the user is logged in, to simply have a session variable setup and check that on the different page that require access permission. If I have a valid session then I can let the user view the page.

I can do something like:

```
       Session["ValidUser"] = "ValidUser";
```

One thing that I am not sure about is that the user view site for  10 hours after login. How do I adjust it so that the session will not timeout. Also is the session variable the best way to go.

Thanks

Comment: Whats wrong with a secure cookie? You can set the `Secure` attribute on it or set `<httpCookies requireSSL="true" />` in the webconfig

Answer (score 0):

Sessions are the standard method for persisting data between pages in asp.net.  However, you are not going to want to keep sessions around for 10 hours.  By default, I believe it is 20 minutes.

You can extend the timeout, but I would recommend storing a cookie or something equivalent.

Comment: What do you mean by something equivalent? Are you refering to view state? or query string?

Comment: I think the most secure is session state, and maybe you are right about not keeping it for 10 hours, but I think if he is only storing a single variable in it then it is ok

Answer (score -1):

Yes, the session state is the best solution if you are not using the built in asp.net membership, and it is the most secure,

you can change the session timeout to more than ten hours by adding this to your web.config file, where timeout is messured in minutes

```
<system.web>
 <sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="600" />
</system.web>
```

Comment: Sessions are not persistent storage. The more you increase the session timeout, the greater chance you have of users leaving sessions open, which means the server will be wasting resources in saving the session data for longer times. Depending on the activity on the site, this could be catastrophic performance wise..

Comment: You are right, sessions should not be kept for ten hours, but it is more secure than storing the variable in a cookie, especiall that he is using it for membership authenticstion. But also you wrong about "Sessions are not Persistent Storage", what are they then !!!!

Comment: Are you not familiar with secure cookies? Setting the `Secure` flag will prevent the cookie being sent with the request over a non HTTPS scheme, they also can't be read by client side script. This is perfectly fine and I believe the default implementation of asp.net membership relies on this (`ASPXAUTH cookie`?)

Comment: Thanks for explaining this, but I am not sure if the default authentication of asp.net membership relies on this